# Лог команд во время сборки проекта в Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Где можно посмотреть лог команд(событий) во время сборки проекта на С++ в Visual Studio 2017?
Мне нужно получить команды для сборки моего проекта с помощью **cl**

Answer (score 0):

Самостоятельно нашёл решение этой проблемы. Для этого:
1. Заходим в командную строку и выполняем там команду для настройки переменных окружения для работы с инструментами сборки Visual Studio:

```
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat"
```

В команде вместо vcvarsx86_amd64.bat можно указать vcvarsamd64_x86.bat, vcvars32.bat или vcvars64.bat (в зависимости от требований к архитектуре инструментов сборки).

2. Переходим в папку проекта Visual Studio, например у меня это команда:

   cd C:\Users\XopmoH\source\repos\Magic
3. Выполняем команду (конфигурацию сборки поменяйте на нужную):

   MSBuild /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="X86"

В итоге начнётся сборка проекта с подробным выводом всего процесса сборки (в том числе выводит команды сборки)